# Excel VBA not catching invalid properties at compile time

Tags: excel, vba, properties, compiler-errors

Excel/VBA compiler doesn't seem to catch invalid properties at compile time. Here's a simple example:-

```
Option Explicit
Sub CompileExample()
    Application.Calculzzzzzzzzation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

It will fail at runtime of course but compiles just fine. Ordinarily this wouldn't be a problem for me but I'm trying to compile some machine-generated code for obvious errors without executing it. Any way for force the compiler to perform strict checking?

Answer (score 3):

The Excel `Application` object has a lot of methods that are `late bound`. Many of them are well-known, i.e. those of the worksheet functions. Therefore the compiler cannot check and reject at compile time any call related to the `Application` object, such as `Application.Calculzzzzzzzzation`. Such a name that is not matched at compile time will be left to the running time for eventual late-binding.

Therefore you need to be careful when working with the `Application` object. The compiler won't detect wrongly written method names; the run-time will do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not just the Application object though. Seems to be the whole object model. Another example:-     
    
    Dim cT As ChartTitle
    cT.Tzzzzzop = 564

Comment: @TokyoD not the whole object model but really *many* of its classes. For example try it with `Worksheet` it wont compile. Try it with `Sheet` and it will (i.e. `Sheets(1).fooo`)

Comment: You're right. Worksheet won't compile with invalid names so not everything. Ok so I guess there's nothing I can do about the late bound classes.. no way to force a strict compile. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer sounds very incorrect to me. In my experience, the compiler always catches invalid object members, if the object variable is declared as a specific object-type. That's the whole point of early-binding.